# remove each li item todo list using on click

Tags: javascript, function, dom, dom-events

I intended to make a todo list but I'm getting a problem that i wanna make a button that come inline in list item like so `<li>my task</li><button>Delete</button>`
but my delete button isn't deleting items correctly it only deletes one items and then start giving error

***this is my code, please look here and also tell me what kind of mistakes I'm doing I'm very beginner in web development***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task" onfocus="this.value=''" id="myTask">
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <button onclick="deleteTask()">del it</button>

    <ol id="myList">

    </ol>



    <script>
        function myFunction() {
           
            var node = document.createElement("LI");
            var myTask = document.getElementById("myTask").value;
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(myTask);
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
            var btn = document.createElement("input");
            var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('LI');

            for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++){
                abcElements[i].id = 'abc-' + i;
            }
            // node.setAttribute("id", "li1");
            btn.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            btn.setAttribute("value", "delete");
            btn.setAttribute("id", "delete");
            node.appendChild(btn);
            btn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                // console.log("OK");
                document.getElementById("abc-0").parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById("abc-0"))

            })

        }

        function deleteTask() {
            var i = 0;
            var item = document.getElementsByTagName("LI")[i];
            i++;
            item.parentNode.removeChild(item);
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**So I just want to make a delete button with every list item as I click on *Try it* button**

Comment: Can you add the code as a code snippet so we can test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to address:

- Don't call a function myFuntion. Give it a descriptive name, like addTask
- Don't create id-attributes with sequential numbers. That is almost never needed.
- The initial HTML should not have a delete button, since it should associate with a list item.
- Don't make the type of the delete button "submit". That only makes sense when you have a `form` element, and need to submit the form.
- Don't give the created button the same id over and over again: that is invalid in HTML. id-attributes should have unique values. But again, it is rarely needed to assign an id to dynamically generated elements.
- In an event listener you can use the event object to get the element on which the event was fired. Or you can use the `this` object in a `function`. But you can also reference the `node` variable that exists in the so-called closure.

```js
function addTask() {
    var node = document.createElement("LI");
    node.textContent = document.getElementById("myTask").value;

    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.textContent = "delete";
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => node.remove());
    node.appendChild(btn);

    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
}
```

```css
li > button { margin-left: 5px }
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task" onfocus="this.value=''" id="myTask">
<button onclick="addTask()">Add task</button>
<ol id="myList"></ol>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for teaching me. have a good day sir

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
function myFunction() {
   const li = document.createElement("li");
   li.innerHTML = document.getElementById("myTask").value;

   const button = document.createElement("button");
   button.innerHTML = "delete";
   
   li.appendChild(button);
   button.addEventListener("click", () => li.parentNode.removeChild(li));

   document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(li);
}
```